# In C#, how can I change a solidbrush color dynamically using numericupdown control?

Tags: c#, colors, numericupdown

Heres the code I'm using:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Colors_Form
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public int RedValue;
            public int GreenValue;
            public int BlueValue;
            public SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
            {
                Graphics g = e.Graphics;
                RedValue = (int)RedNumBox.Value;
                GreenValue = (int)GreenNumBox.Value;
                BlueValue = (int)BlueNumBox.Value;

                //SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue ));
                g.FillRectangle(sb, 10, 150, 300, 200);
            }

            private void RedNumBox_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue));


            }

            private void GreenNumBox_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                GreenValue = (int)GreenNumBox.Value;
                sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue));
            }

            private void BlueNumBox_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BlueValue = (int)GreenNumBox.Value;
                sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue));
            }
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is get the solid brush to change color when the 'valuechanged' event is triggered. Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful. I have tried variations on:

```
    sb = sb.Color(Color.FromArgb(255,RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue));
```

but that code fails as well. I placed the solid brush globally, so there could be access to it from any method created. I have looked everywhere and cannot find any color update instructions and all I see is 'new brush' and now, I'm unsure how to proceed. I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: After changing the brush you need to trigger the paint by `Invalidating` the form.

Comment: You may need to call Invalidate() after setting a new value for sb.

Comment: `BlueValue = (int)GreenNumBox.Value;`

Just pointing out that you're setting the BlueValue to the value in the green box... :)

Comment: @DanielForslund, thanks, I just updated the error.

Comment: A drawing object like SolidBrush needs to be disposed after usage.  Do *not* make it a member of your class, create it when you paint.  Which now lets you use the `using` statement.  Caching it is actively harmful, cheap to create but expensive to store.

Comment: @Hans: While the general advice is certainly right for newbies, can you explain how _Caching [a brush] is actively harmful_ ?? I have seen advice to the contrary that makes more sense to me. If a program needs one or a few (!) pens, brushes, fonts why not cache them instead of creating them thousand or millions of times? Of course one mustn't leak them..

Comment: I explained it in the comment.  Creating a brush only takes a microsecond.  But is stored on the desktop heap, which can only store 65535 drawing objects for all programs.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the brush into the paint event and remove the global variable.  SolidBrush should be disposed of when its done.  Better to do that in one place than all the change events.

```
using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue )))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(sb, 10, 150, 300, 200);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevbo! Your help was invaluable!

Comment: @jake.lange & TaW, I used Refresh() instead of Invalidate(). Thanks for the help!